# Android Google Play: I need to upload Video Files along with apk file and download them after Purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I need to upload video files to the Google play user can download these files after performing in-App Purchase.How can I upload them? There are more than ten files Which I need to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uploaded videos on Google drive made it public and then created its link and than I downloaded file using this link.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to upload that video file to your server and download it when your app runs. I don't know of any way where you can put video files separately on Google play. So what you want can be implemented if you use your own server for downloading the video file.

Comment: Actually I'm saving my cost of making other server for uploading videos.I was think that If google play give a space for uploading files which would be downloaded after purchase.Apple account gives this option I was wondering why google dont give that option?

Comment: @RobinRoyal Why don't you put the file as Public on G Drive and download it from there. I think that might work.

Comment: If that solved your problem please mark the answer as correct